# Speeding up ORDER BY date

Tags: mysql

**EDIT: `releases.date` is now `DATE` type**

I am running the following query which takes around 5 seconds to run. As this is a web app this is far too slow to be usable.

```
SELECT releases.* ,COUNT(charts_extended.release_id) as num 
        FROM releases_all releases force index (date)           
        JOIN recommendations
        ON releases.id=recommendations.release_id 
        JOIN charts_extended 
        ON charts_extended.release_id=releases.id 
        LEFT JOIN charts_extended ce
            ON ce.release_id=releases.id
            AND ce.artist='Si Quick'
        LEFT JOIN dislike
            ON dislike.release_id=releases.id
            AND dislike.user='Si Quick'
            WHERE dislike.release_id IS NULL 
        AND ce.release_id IS NULL 
        AND recommendations.user='Si Quick'
        AND datediff(now(),releases.date) >=0
        GROUP BY releases.id
        ORDER BY releases.date DESC 
        LIMIT 0,41
```

EXPLAIN returns the following:

```
1   SIMPLE  releases    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    77226   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  ce  ref release_id,artist   release_id  4   soundshe.releases.id    4   Using where; Not exists
1   SIMPLE  recommendations ref user,release_id release_id  4   soundshe.releases.id    39  Using where
1   SIMPLE  dislike ref release_id,user user    203 const   105 Using where
1   SIMPLE  charts_extended ref release_id  release_id  4   soundshe.releases.id    4   Using index
```

`Using temporary` and `Using filesort` are slowing down the query considerably. If i remove the `ORDER BY releases.date DESC` command then the query runs in ~1 second.

Data in the `releases.date` field is in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` and is a `VARCHAR` type.

How can I speed up this `ORDER BY`? I have set an index on the field.

Comment: is `date` also the name of the index on the `date` column? Otherwise the `FORCE INDEX (date)` won't work at all.

Comment: Never ever use GROUP BY this way. It is a weakness in MySQL. A "proper" use of group by requires you to SPECIFY EVERY (non-aggregating) COLUMN from the select clause  in the group by clause. So never ever use "select *" and group by in the same query.

Comment: @FMashiro yes `date` is the name of the index

Comment: Is the `date` column actually a DATETIME type? or a string that looks like a date?

Comment: Ouch, the VARCHAR is a bad idea, you're better off changing it to a DATE datatype.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the Join fields and the Where fields?

Comment: yes, varchar is awful for this or any other date operation.

Comment: `releases.date` is now `DATE` type

Comment: Yes to indexes on the join and where fields

Comment: Is there a covering index on (`ce.release`, `ce.artist`) and on (`dislike.release_id`, `dislike.user`) ? (as in, two indexes, that each cover the two mentionned columns in the order they were mentioned)

Comment: How many rows do you get for `SELECT * from recommendations where user='Si Quick'` as a percentage of the total row count in recommendations? Not knowing your data, it feels like it might potentially be faster to start with (and index) this column/table instead of `releases`. How many rows does `releases` have, and how many rows do you get as a result for your query (without the limit of course)? And to follow up FMashiros question: Does removing the two `left joins` (and the first two comparisons in your `where`) speed up your query? (Just to test it, I know it might change your result).

Comment: @Franco can you make an sql fiddle with sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most bang for buck, from easiest to hardest:

1. Choose only the fields you need. * can actually add a considerable overhead. Just try deleting that bit and see how much of an improvement you get.

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(charts_extended.release_id) as num
   ```
2. Consider using an integer field as an index instead, since dates can be duplicated. If the date actually a date and not a datetime, the index is worse. I dont think this is actually doing anything judging from your explain statement.

   ```
   FROM releases_all releases force index (date)
   ```
3. Ensure everything in your WHERE clause has an index setup.
4. Pass a datetime in here manually instead of `now()` so it can cache, this will currently cook up the resultset from scratch each time. You are looking for stuff in the past, so you can probably do this with a datediff of **from tomorrow** since music albums/records are usually released on Tuesday 28th September, rather than Tuesday 28th September **at 9AM**. This will do the work once rather than each time per parameter. This will be using a parameter in an SQL statement of course.
   You can try inserting a date by hand in the meantime and running the query twice to see what I mean:

   ```
   AND datediff("2017-06-28 00:00:00",releases.date) >=0
   GROUP BY releases.id
   ORDER BY releases.date DESC 
   LIMIT 0,41
   ```

Here is your new improved query with parameters injected, run it twice to see if you get any improvement:

```
SELECT COUNT(charts_extended.release_id) as num 
        FROM releases_all releases         
        JOIN recommendations
        ON releases.id=recommendations.release_id 
        JOIN charts_extended 
        ON charts_extended.release_id=releases.id 
        LEFT JOIN charts_extended ce
            ON ce.release_id=releases.id
            AND ce.artist='Si Quick'
        LEFT JOIN dislike
            ON dislike.release_id=releases.id
            AND dislike.user='Si Quick'
            WHERE dislike.release_id IS NULL 
        AND ce.release_id IS NULL 
        AND recommendations.user='Si Quick'
        AND datediff("2017-06-28 00:00:00",releases.date) >0
        GROUP BY releases.id
        ORDER BY releases.date DESC 
        LIMIT 0,41
```

Comment: This was a great answer, and it cut the query time in half. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Why it is slow**

The performance problem is what I call "inflate-deflate".  First the `JOINs` inflate the number of 'rows' to look at, then the `GROUP BY` deflates back to (in this case) the number of rows (or maybe fewer) than in the original table.

So, there are two purposes of the `GROUP BY` -- for the aggregate (`COUNT`) and for the 'deflate'.  Let's see if we can avoid the deflate.

Because it cannot focus on just the 41 desired rows, it will gather *the entire `releases_all` table*, sort it, and *then* deliver 41 rows.  If there are `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns, the bulkiness of this task could be bad.

**FORCE is bad**

But first, let me explain why `force index (date)` is either useless or hurts performance.  The `GROUP BY` must be done before the `ORDER BY` (unless they can be done simultaneously, but they can't).

`PRIMARY KEY(id)` is probably used to help with the `GROUP BY`, but anything after that (namely the `ORDER BY`) cannot use an index.  So, again, getting rid of `GROUP BY` might help.

**Overview of better query**

Here's the goal:

```
SELECT r2.*,
       ( SELECT release_id,
                COUNT(charts_extended.release_id) as num
             FROM release_id
             JOIN ...
             WHERE ...
             ORDER BY r1.date DESC
             LIMIT 41
             OFFSET 0
       ) as num
    FROM releases_all AS r2
    ORDER BY releases.date DESC
    LIMIT 0, 41;
```

Notes:

- `GROUP BY` is gone, at least from the outer query.
- `ORDER BY` is repeated (since the Optimizer is not obligated to keep the subquery's order).
- `OFFSET` shows up only in the subquery.  (I assume you are "paginating".  Here is a discussion of why "why pagination via OFFSET" is bad, and a possible improvement:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination )
- `INDEX(date)` is needed.
- We still need to develop the subquery...

Offhand, the subquery is the original query, but selecting only

```
SELECT r1.id, r1.date
```

But, before finishing the query, you need to decide where `x.user='Si Quick'` lives.  It makes a difference whether it is in `ON` or `WHERE`.

**Possible optimizations**

- Avoid the inflate-deflate.
- Touch only 41 rows of the various `JOINed` tables.
- Touch lots of rows to get the `COUNTs`, but only 41 when doing `SELECT release.*` (see comment on `BLOB`).
- `INDEX(date, id)` *may* help; add it.

**Potential problem**

Which 41 rows do you want?  Because of all of the `JOINs`, it won't necessarily be the 'last' (`ORDER BY date desc`) 41; you might be skipping some of them.

I can't finish the task for you because I don't know the relationships.  Is releases_all:recommendations 1:1?  1:many?  Sometimes 1:0?  Please tell us that, plus the rest of the relationships needed in the `JOINs` and `LEFT JOIN`.

I cannot tell (yet) whether the subquery can efficiently deliver the "last" 41 rows, or whether it will have to compute all the `COUNTs` before settling on only 41.

**Finishing the subquery**

Rip out everything but the `COUNT(charts_extended.release_id)` and see how simple you can make the `SELECT` to get that `COUNT`.  You can *probably* avoid touching `releases_all` at all.

**Inefficient NOW comparison**

Also, don't "hide an indexed column inside a function".  That is, instead of

```
AND  datediff(now(),releases.date) >=0
```

use

```
AND  releases.date <= CURDATE()
```

(This also fixes the `DATE` vs `DATETIME` issue.)

Answer (score 0):

Without access to your tables and content it is guesswork trying to set-up relevant test cases. For each table I have setup secondary indexes that I think will be appropriate to your query. In addition I have suggested using NOT EXISTS instead of the LEFT OUTER for dislikes.

The series of queries I have used are paired with explain plans so that you may trace the effect of each additional part of the query.

Whether this is faster or not I cannot know unless you perform trials.`

Possibly because my test data is so small filesort is used throughout.

> ```
> create table if not exists releases_all (
>     id           mediumint not null auto_increment
>   , `date`       date not null
>   , name         varchar(80)
>   , blurb        varchar(200)
>   , PRIMARY KEY (id) 
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE INDEX idx_release_date ON releases_all (`date`);
> ```

> ```
> insert into releases_all (`date`, name, blurb)
> values (STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-15', '%Y-%m-%d'), 'blah', 'ub1')
>       ,(STR_TO_DATE('2014-05-05', '%Y-%m-%d'), 'blah', 'ub2')
>       ,(STR_TO_DATE('2015-02-25', '%Y-%m-%d'), 'blah', 'ub1')
>       ,(STR_TO_DATE('2015-05-02', '%Y-%m-%d'), 'blah', 'ub2')
>       ,(STR_TO_DATE('2016-04-08', '%Y-%m-%d'), 'blah', 'ub1')
>       ,(STR_TO_DATE('2016-07-15', '%Y-%m-%d'), 'blah', 'ub2')
>       ,(STR_TO_DATE('2016-03-01', '%Y-%m-%d'), 'blah', 'ub3')
>       ,(STR_TO_DATE('2017-02-28', '%Y-%m-%d'), 'blah', 'ub2')
>       ,(STR_TO_DATE('2017-06-19', '%Y-%m-%d'), 'blah', 'ub3')
>        ;
> ```

> ```
> create table if not exists recommendations (
>   id           mediumint not null auto_increment,
>   release_id   mediumint not null,
>   `user`         varchar(20),
>   PRIMARY KEY  (id)
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE INDEX idx_user_release ON recommendations (`user`, release_id);
> ```

> ```
> insert into recommendations (release_id, `user`)
> values (1, 'user1')
>      , (2, 'user1')
>      , (3, 'user1')
>      , (4, 'user1')
>      , (5, 'user1')
>      , (6, 'user1')
>      , (7, 'user1')
>      , (8, 'user1')
>      , (9, 'user1')
>      ;
> ```

> ```
> create table if not exists charts_extended (
>   id           mediumint not null auto_increment,
>   release_id   mediumint not null,
>   artist       varchar(20),
>   PRIMARY KEY  (id)
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE INDEX idx_artist_release ON charts_extended (artist, release_id);
> ```

> ```
> insert into charts_extended (release_id, artist)
> values (1, 'Si Quick')
>      , (2, 'Si Quick')
>      , (3, 'Si Quick')
>      , (4, 'Si Quick')
>      , (5, 'Si Quick')
>      , (6, 'Si Quick')
>      , (7, 'Si Quick')
>      , (8, 'Si Quick')
>      , (9, 'Si Quick')
>      ;
> ```

> ```
> create table if not exists dislike (
>   id           mediumint not null auto_increment,
>   release_id   mediumint not null,
>   `user`         varchar(20),
>   PRIMARY KEY  (id)
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE INDEX idx_user_release ON dislike (`user`, release_id);
> ```

> ```
> insert into dislike (release_id, `user`)
> values (1, 'Si Quick')
>      , (2, 'Si Quick')
>      , (3, 'Si Quick')
>      , (4, 'Si Quick')
>      ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     releases.* 
> FROM releases_all releases force index (idx_release_date)
> where NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
>                 FROM dislike
>                 WHERE dislike.release_id=releases.id AND dislike.user='Si Quick'
>                 )
> ORDER BY releases.`date`
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date       | name | blurb
> -: | :--------- | :--- | :----
>  7 | 2016-03-01 | blah | ub3  
>  5 | 2016-04-08 | blah | ub1  
>  6 | 2016-07-15 | blah | ub2  
>  8 | 2017-02-28 | blah | ub2  
>  9 | 2017-06-19 | blah | ub3
> ```

> ```
> explain extended
> SELECT
>     releases.* 
> FROM releases_all releases force index (idx_release_date)
> where NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
>                 FROM dislike
>                 WHERE dislike.release_id=releases.id AND dislike.user='Si Quick'
>                 )
> ORDER BY releases.`date`
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type  | table    | type  | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                   
> -: | :----------- | :------- | :---- | :--------------- | :--------------- | :------ | :---- | ---: | -------: | :-----------------------
>  1 | PRIMARY      | releases | index | null             | idx_release_date | 3       | null  |    9 |   100.00 | Using where             
>  2 | MATERIALIZED | dislike  | ref   | idx_user_release | idx_user_release | 23      | const |    4 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     releases.* 
> FROM releases_all releases force index (idx_release_date)
> LEFT JOIN charts_extended ce ON ce.release_id=releases.id AND ce.artist='Si Quick'
> where NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
>                   FROM dislike
>                   WHERE dislike.release_id=releases.id AND dislike.user='Si Quick'
>                  )
> ORDER BY releases.`date`
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date       | name | blurb
> -: | :--------- | :--- | :----
>  7 | 2016-03-01 | blah | ub3  
>  5 | 2016-04-08 | blah | ub1  
>  6 | 2016-07-15 | blah | ub2  
>  8 | 2017-02-28 | blah | ub2  
>  9 | 2017-06-19 | blah | ub3
> ```

> ```
> explain extended
> SELECT
>     releases.* 
> FROM releases_all releases force index (idx_release_date)
> LEFT JOIN charts_extended ce ON ce.release_id=releases.id AND ce.artist='Si Quick'
> where NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
>                   FROM dislike
>                   WHERE dislike.release_id=releases.id AND dislike.user='Si Quick'
>                  )
> ORDER BY releases.`date`
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type  | table    | type | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref                                           | rows | filtered | Extra                      
> -: | :----------- | :------- | :--- | :----------------- | :----------------- | :------ | :-------------------------------------------- | ---: | -------: | :--------------------------
>  1 | PRIMARY      | releases | ALL  | null               | null               | null    | null                                          |    9 |   100.00 | Using where; Using filesort
>  1 | PRIMARY      | ce       | ref  | idx_artist_release | idx_artist_release | 26      | const,fiddle_NNENRNYWCZCRQJZAHBRY.releases.id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index   
>  2 | MATERIALIZED | dislike  | ref  | idx_user_release   | idx_user_release   | 23      | const                                         |    4 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     releases.* 
> FROM releases_all releases force index (idx_release_date)
> INNER JOIN recommendations rec ON releases.id = rec.release_id
> LEFT JOIN charts_extended ce ON releases.id = ce.release_id AND ce.artist = 'Si Quick'
> where NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
>                   FROM dislike
>                   WHERE releases.id = dislike.release_id AND dislike.user = 'Si Quick'
>                  )
> and rec.user = 'user1'
> ORDER BY releases.`date`
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date       | name | blurb
> -: | :--------- | :--- | :----
>  7 | 2016-03-01 | blah | ub3  
>  5 | 2016-04-08 | blah | ub1  
>  6 | 2016-07-15 | blah | ub2  
>  8 | 2017-02-28 | blah | ub2  
>  9 | 2017-06-19 | blah | ub3
> ```

> ```
> explain extended
> SELECT
>     releases.* 
> FROM releases_all releases force index (idx_release_date)
> INNER JOIN recommendations rec ON releases.id = rec.release_id
> LEFT JOIN charts_extended ce ON releases.id = ce.release_id AND ce.artist = 'Si Quick'
> where NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
>                   FROM dislike
>                   WHERE releases.id = dislike.release_id AND dislike.user = 'Si Quick'
>                  )
> and rec.user = 'user1'
> ORDER BY releases.`date`
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type  | table    | type | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref                                           | rows | filtered | Extra                      
> -: | :----------- | :------- | :--- | :----------------- | :----------------- | :------ | :-------------------------------------------- | ---: | -------: | :--------------------------
>  1 | PRIMARY      | releases | ALL  | null               | null               | null    | null                                          |    9 |   100.00 | Using where; Using filesort
>  1 | PRIMARY      | rec      | ref  | idx_user_release   | idx_user_release   | 26      | const,fiddle_NNENRNYWCZCRQJZAHBRY.releases.id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index   
>  1 | PRIMARY      | ce       | ref  | idx_artist_release | idx_artist_release | 26      | const,fiddle_NNENRNYWCZCRQJZAHBRY.releases.id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index   
>  2 | MATERIALIZED | dislike  | ref  | idx_user_release   | idx_user_release   | 23      | const                                         |    4 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=eb65dcd1d91c7379d46e702f43543de9)*

Answer (score -1):

Please try this query. I have moved 'AND' conditions from main 'WHERE' conditions to its respective 'LEFT' join conditions. This will help LEFT join to filter rows and hence process only that rows that are needed. As a result of that 'ORDER BY' command has only required rows to process. I hope that helps.

```
SELECT releases.* ,COUNT(charts_extended.release_id) as num 
FROM releases_all releases force index (date)   
JOIN recommendations ON releases.id=recommendations.release_id AND recommendations.user='Si Quick'
JOIN charts_extended ON charts_extended.release_id=releases.id 
LEFT JOIN charts_extended ce ON ce.release_id=releases.id AND ce.artist='Si Quick' AND ce.release_id IS NULL
LEFT JOIN dislike ON dislike.release_id=releases.id AND dislike.user='Si Quick' AND dislike.release_id IS NULL
WHERE datediff(now(),releases.date) >=0
GROUP BY releases.id
ORDER BY releases.date DESC 
LIMIT 0,41
```

Comment: While you usually can move conditions around (although relational algebra will do it on its own while translating the query, so you don't have to do it yourself), in this case, it is actually wrong. The point of `ce.release_id IS NULL` in `where` is to find rows in `releases` that do NOT have corresponding rows in `ce`, while your rewritten condition is never true. It reads `ce.release_id=releases.id AND ... ce.release_id IS NULL`, so it is equivalent to `releases.id=NULL`; this is actually never true, even if `releases.id` (which is probably the primary key) would be `null` for some reason.

Comment: Please provide me sql dump with data. I will provide you optimised query after running few tests on my machine.

Comment: If that was a response to my comment: it's not my question (so I cannot provide you with the dump), just wanted to point out that you cannot rewrite the code that way.